# count rows of a file with same first character

Tags: php

In a comma separated csv file, I want to count the number of rows only where the the first number is same.

Following is the example data, I want to get number of rows which start with 2 (2 rows), and the rows which start with 4 (3 rows). This is just an example, the numbers are random.:

```
2,0,0
2,1,0
4,0,0
4,3,0
4,4,0
```

I'm trying following code, I can count only all rows of the file but do not know how can I count only the rows which have same first number.

```
$i = 0;

while ($i < 5) {    //fixed number of times
    $i++;   

    $rows = 0;
    $fp = fopen("test.csv", "r");
        while (fgetcsv($fp)) {  //don't want all rows
            $rows++;
        }
    fclose($fp);    
    echo $rows;
}
```

**Edit:**
Sorry, I forgot to mention the numbers in above file are random, they are not always 2 or 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an array to get statistics.

```
$i   = 0;
$agg = []; // to count stats

while ($i < 5) {
    $i++;   

    $rows = 0;
    $fp = fopen("test.csv", "r");

    while ($line = fgetcsv($fp)) {
        $number = $line[0]; // get first number

        if(isset($agg[$number])){  // if there is the number in stats
            $agg[$number]++;       // count new one
        } else {
            $agg[$number] = 1;     // mark as found one
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);

    print_r($agg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try something like this :

```
$i = 0;

while ($i < 5) {    //fixed number of times
    $i++;   

    $rows = array();
    $fp = fopen("test.csv", "r");
        while ($data = fgetcsv($fp)) {
            $first = $data[0];
            if(isset($rows[$first]) {
                $rows[$first] += 1;
            } else {
                $rows[$first] = 1;
            }
        }
    fclose($fp);    
    print_r($rows);
}
```

I didn't test my code, so it may contains errors.

After the execution, `$rows` will contain an associative array with the form `'first number' => 'count'`

What I don't understand however is why you are doing it five times and also why you are not using a `for` loop for that instead of a `while` ?

Comment: I'm not a smart person. The first loop will run for fixed number of times, I'll try for loop, but I am just unable to count the number of rows which have same first number.

Comment: what I don't understand is why looping  5 times ? @hal9000 thanks for the correction, I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to get the contents of the text file, something like this should work:

```
$ar = explode("\n",$txtfileContents);
$counts = array();
foreach($ar as $row){
      $counts[$row[0]]++;
}
```

`$counts` now contains an array of all first characters and how many times they appeared. You can now simply access them like this:

```
echo "'2' appeared ".$count['2']." times<br/>";
echo "'4' appeared ".$count['4']." times";
```

**Step by step:**

Split the text file into an array of individual rows:

```
$ar = explode("\n",$txtfileContents);
```

(Try alternatively [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) here, which may be more reliable than explode)

Loop through it:

```
foreach($ar as $row){
      
}
```

Then check the first character inside the loop and count each character separately:

```
$counts[$row[0]]++;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer and do not know who down voted.

Comment: @cronoklee I downvoted you because your answer it not correct based on the fact that he want to have the count for each possible starting number. Also, it your solution won't be able to handle cases where it is a number and not only a digit. It also seems that the data is CSV as indicated by the use of `fgetcsv` in the question

Comment: I've downvoted for usage of `explode('/n' ...)`. There is no `/n` - it is probably typo. The main reason, is that use of [`file()`](http://php.net/file) is more reliable here. Also, @krtek noted parameter-handprinting.

Comment: Updated answer to count each character and fixed typos. Also tested and it works perfectly

Comment: @krtek The question title clearly states "count rows of a file with same first character". Nothing about double digit numbers & nothing about CSV. The fact that the OP is using a CSV file is arbitrary; Googlers will land here looking for a solution for text files.

Comment: @cronoklee The first sentence clearly states " I want to count the number of rows only where the the first number is same." and AFAIK a number can have multiple digits. Reading only the title is often not the best way to answer a question on SO ;)

Comment: @HAL9000 - file() is more reliable here - updated - thanks for the tip.